# Why are updates to Android apps on Google Play Billing version 2 being rejected ahead of the November 1 2021 deadline to update to version 3?

Tags: android, google-play, playback, billing

Direct quote from Google, found in link below:

"Starting August 2, 2021, all **new** apps must use Billing Library version 3 or newer. By **November 1, 2021**, all **updates** to existing apps must use Billing Library version 3 or newer."

However, apps attempting to update as of August 2 (yesterday) are being rejected due to using Billing Library version 2. Only **new** apps should be rejected, not existing apps that are **updating**.

**Question: Google or other developers, why is this happening, and how can we submit updates to apps using Billing v2 to be accepted before the November 1 2021 deadline?**

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/meet-google-play-billing-library.html

Comment: i think all apps are concerned...So you have to update to billing 3 (actually def billing_version = "4.0.0")

Comment: BTW, does it mean that the apps NOT using Billing Library must add it?